# cannot catch missing DLL file (VB.NET VS2019)

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a program which uses several DLL files. Most are from nuget source. I used to check (within main_Load()), if the dll files are present locally and in case of missing dll files, I download them from an own webserver. This works fine. Now I have added a reference to a custom DLL file (because these functions should be shared among serveral programs from several developers). However, I an not able to check this DLLs presence. Even before Program start I get a .NET Framework error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Main() method must be jitted before your program can start running.  Seems that its code uses that custom DLL, so the program fails with an uncatchable exception before it can start running.  You'll have to refactor Main() to not need it, and only do the file checking, move the rest of the code into a separate helper method that you call from Main().  Give it the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute to be sure.

Comment: Thank you Hans,
it's a pity for Microsoft to throw this exception. It was enough to seperate the DLL function call into a seperate Sub which I call from main_load. Now I am able to check and download the missing DLL file.